# CIFilter and RAW image support on Yosemite

Tags: macos, photo, osx-yosemite, core-image

I'm playing around a bit with Core Image, CIFilter and RAW images. If I understand Apple's documentation correctly, to load a RAW image and display it in an image view, some code like this should do the trick:

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"file:///Users/emiel/Desktop/_MG_1087.CR2"];
//  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"file:///Users/emiel/Desktop/_DSC0044.NEF"];

    CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithImageURL:url options:nil];

    NSLog(@"CIFilter: %@", filter);

    CIImage *image = filter.outputImage;

    NSCIImageRep *rep = [NSCIImageRep imageRepWithCIImage:image];
    NSLog(@"%f - %f", rep.size.width, rep.size.height);

    NSImage *nsImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:CGSizeMake(rep.size.width, rep.size.height)];
    [nsImage addRepresentation:rep];

    self.imageView.image = nsImage;
```

This code works fine for the .NEF (Nikon RAW) file, but the CR2 (Canon RAW) file gives me a totally black image. The image dimensions of the black image are correct though. What is going wrong here? Do I need to set some default to a non-default value? Preview/Aperture/iPhoto/etc all work fine with my .CR2 image, so it is possible to read them.

The only difference I can find is that apparently, for the CR2 file a version 6 of the decoder is used, and the NEF file is decoded by version 5. If I set the CR2 to be decoded by version 5 all works, but this seems to be a weird solution since I don't know if there is a version 5 or 6 or whatever for other RAW image formats.

NEF File:

```
{CIRAWFilterImpl {
    inputBias = 3;
    inputBoost = 1;
    inputBoostShadowAmount = "0.9";
    inputColorNoiseReductionAmount = "0.5";
    inputDecoderVersion = 5;
    inputDraftMode = 0;
    inputEV = 0;
    inputEnableNoiseTracking = 1;
    inputEnableSharpening = 1;
    inputEnableVendorLensCorrection = 0;
    inputIgnoreOrientation = "<null>";
    inputImageOrientation = 1;
    inputLinearSpaceFilter = "<null>";
    inputLuminanceNoiseReductionAmount = "0.1";
    inputNeutralChromaticityX = "0.4212473792917087";
    inputNeutralChromaticityY = "0.4060714400950335";
    inputNeutralLocation = "[]";
    inputNeutralTemperature = "3296.579476861167";
    inputNeutralTint = "3.848452212530264";
    inputNoiseReductionAmount = "<null>";
    inputNoiseReductionContrastAmount = 0;
    inputNoiseReductionDetailAmount = 0;
    inputNoiseReductionSharpnessAmount = "0.5";
    inputScaleFactor = 1;
}}
```

CR2 File:

```
{CIRAWFilterImpl {
    inputBias = 3;
    inputBoost = 1;
    inputBoostShadowAmount = "0.9";
    inputColorNoiseReductionAmount = "0.5";
    inputDecoderVersion = 6;
    inputDraftMode = 0;
    inputEV = 0;
    inputEnableNoiseTracking = 1;
    inputEnableSharpening = 1;
    inputEnableVendorLensCorrection = 0;
    inputIgnoreOrientation = "<null>";
    inputImageOrientation = 1;
    inputLinearSpaceFilter = "<null>";
    inputLuminanceNoiseReductionAmount = 0;
    inputNeutralChromaticityX = "0.3575430840790828";
    inputNeutralChromaticityY = "0.3599707869545071";
    inputNeutralLocation = "[]";
    inputNeutralTemperature = "4585.861752390336";
    inputNeutralTint = "-11.18923977879745";
    inputNoiseReductionAmount = "<null>";
    inputNoiseReductionContrastAmount = 0;
    inputNoiseReductionDetailAmount = 0;
    inputNoiseReductionSharpnessAmount = "0.5";
    inputScaleFactor = 1;
}}
```

Help?

Comment: Write a Radar and someone at Apple will look into this.

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a regression in 10.10.2 and/or the latest RAW compatibility update, according to posts in Apple's Devforums.  The only known workaround is to manually override inputDecoderVersion to 5.

Please also file a Radar, so that Apple takes notice.