# Does CIRawFilter work on Canon CR2 raw file?

Tags: swift, core-image

It looks like that CIRawFilter don't support Canon CR2 files.

```
let url = URL(string: "file:///Path/to/an/Canon.CR2")!
let rawFilter = CIRAWFilter(imageURL: url)
var indicators: [String: Bool] = [:]
indicators["isDetailSupported"] = rawFilter!.isDetailSupported
indicators["isSharpnessSupported"] = rawFilter!.isSharpnessSupported indicators["isLuminanceNoiseReductionSupported"] = rawFilter!.isLuminanceNoiseReductionSupported
indicators["isLocalToneMapSupported"] = rawFilter!.isLocalToneMapSupported  
indicators["isLensCorrectionSupported"] = rawFilter!.isLensCorrectionSupported  
indicators["isColorNoiseReductionSupported"] = rawFilter!.isColorNoiseReductionSupported  
indicators["isMoireReductionSupported"] = rawFilter!.isMoireReductionSupported  
indicators["isContrastSupported"] = rawFilter!.isContrastSupported  
print(indicators)
```

> ["isDetailSupported": false, "isSharpnessSupported": false, "isLuminanceNoiseReductionSupported": false, "isLocalToneMapSupported": false, "isLensCorrectionSupported": false, "isColorNoiseReductionSupported": false, "isMoireReductionSupported": false, "isContrastSupported": false]`

But Canon.CR2 was taken by Canon EOS 6D, and Canon EOS 6D is on the list of supportedCameraModels.

```swift
print(CIRAWFilter.supportedCameraModels)
```

```
["", "Adobe DNG", "Canon EOS 1000D", "Canon EOS 100D", "Canon EOS 10D", "Canon EOS 1100D", "Canon EOS 1200D", "Canon EOS 1300D", "Canon EOS 1500D", "Canon EOS 2000D", "Canon EOS 200D", "Canon EOS 200D Mark II", "Canon EOS 20D", "Canon EOS 250D", "Canon EOS 3000D", "Canon EOS 300D", "Canon EOS 30D", "Canon EOS 350D", "Canon EOS 4000D", "Canon EOS 400D", "Canon EOS 40D", "Canon EOS 450D", "Canon EOS 500D", "Canon EOS 50D", "Canon EOS 550D", "Canon EOS 5D", "Canon EOS 5D Mark II", "Canon EOS 5D Mark III", "Canon EOS 5D Mark IV", "Canon EOS 5DS", "Canon EOS 5DS R", "Canon EOS 600D", "Canon EOS 60D", "Canon EOS 650D", "Canon EOS 6D", "Canon EOS 6D Mark II", "Canon EOS 700D", "Canon EOS 70D", "Canon EOS 750D", "Canon EOS 760D", "Canon EOS 77D", "Canon EOS 7D", "Canon EOS 7D Mark II", "Canon EOS 800D", "Canon EOS 80D", "Canon EOS 850D", "Canon EOS 9000D", "Canon EOS 90D", "Canon EOS D30", "Canon EOS D60", "Canon EOS Digital Rebel", "Canon EOS Digital Rebel XS", "Canon EOS Digital Rebel XSi", "Canon EOS Digital Rebel XT", "Canon EOS Digital Rebel XTi", "Canon EOS Kiss 8000D", "Canon EOS Kiss Digital", "Canon EOS Kiss Digital F", "Canon EOS Kiss Digital N", "Canon EOS Kiss Digital X", "Canon EOS Kiss Digital X2", "Canon EOS Kiss Digital X3", "Canon EOS Kiss X10i", "Canon EOS Kiss X4", "Canon EOS Kiss X5", "Canon EOS Kiss X50", "Canon EOS Kiss X6i", "Canon EOS Kiss X7", "Canon EOS Kiss X70", "Canon EOS Kiss X7i", "Canon EOS Kiss X80", "Canon EOS Kiss X8i", "Canon EOS M", "Canon EOS M10", "Canon EOS M100", "Canon EOS M2", "Canon EOS M200", "Canon EOS M3", "Canon EOS M5", "Canon EOS M50", "Canon EOS M50 Mark II", "Canon EOS M50m2", "Canon EOS M6 Mark II", "Canon EOS R", "Canon EOS R10", "Canon EOS R3", "Canon EOS R5", "Canon EOS R50", "Canon EOS R5C", "Canon EOS R6", "Canon EOS R6 Mark II", "Canon EOS R7", "Canon EOS R8", "Canon EOS RP", "Canon EOS Rebel SL1", "Canon EOS Rebel SL2", "Canon EOS Rebel SL3", "Canon EOS Rebel T100", "Canon EOS Rebel T1i", "Canon EOS Rebel T2i", "Canon EOS Rebel T3", "Canon EOS Rebel T3i", "Canon EOS Rebel T4i", "Canon EOS Rebel T5", "Canon EOS Rebel T5i", "Canon EOS Rebel T6", "Canon EOS Rebel T6i", "Canon EOS Rebel T6s", "Canon EOS Rebel T7", "Canon EOS Rebel T7i", "Canon EOS Rebel T8i", "Canon EOS-1D", "Canon EOS-1D C", "Canon EOS-1D Mark II", "Canon EOS-1D Mark II N", "Canon EOS-1D Mark III", "Canon EOS-1D Mark IV", "Canon EOS-1D X", "Canon EOS-1D X Mark II", "Canon EOS-1D X Mark III", "Canon EOS-1Ds", "Canon EOS-1Ds Mark II", "Canon EOS-1Ds Mark III", "Canon EOS-M100", "Canon EOS-M6", "Canon Kiss X10", "Canon Kiss X8", "Canon Kiss X9i", "Canon PowerShot G1 X", "Canon PowerShot G1 X Mark II", "Canon PowerShot G1 X Mark III", "Canon PowerShot G10", "Canon PowerShot G11", "Canon PowerShot G12", "Canon PowerShot G15", "Canon PowerShot G16", "Canon PowerShot G3", "Canon PowerShot G3 X", "Canon PowerShot G5", "Canon PowerShot G5 X", "Canon PowerShot G5 X Mark II", "Canon PowerShot G6", "Canon PowerShot G7 X", "Canon PowerShot G7 X Mark II", "Canon PowerShot G7 X Mark III", "Canon PowerShot G9", "Canon PowerShot G9 X", "Canon PowerShot G9 X Mark II", "Canon PowerShot Pro1", "Canon PowerShot S100", "Canon PowerShot S100V", "Canon PowerShot S110", "Canon PowerShot S120", "Canon PowerShot S60", "Canon PowerShot S70", "Canon PowerShot S90", "Canon PowerShot S95", "Canon PowerShot SX1 IS", "Canon PowerShot SX50 HS", "Canon PowerShot SX60 HS", "Canon PowerShot SX70 HS", "DxO ONE", "EOS-1D X Mark III", "Epson R-D1", "Epson R-D1s", "Epson R-D1x", "Fujifilm FinePix S2Pro", "Fujifilm FinePix S3Pro", "Fujifilm FinePix S5Pro", "Fujifilm FinePix X100", "Fujifilm FinePixF550EXR", "Fujifilm GFX 50R", "Fujifilm GFX 50S", "Fujifilm GFX100S", "Fujifilm X-100F", "Fujifilm X-100V", "Fujifilm X-A1", "Fujifilm X-A10", "Fujifilm X-A2", "Fujifilm X-A3", "Fujifilm X-A5", "Fujifilm X-A7", "Fujifilm X-E1", "Fujifilm X-E2", "Fujifilm X-E2S", "Fujifilm X-E3", "Fujifilm X-E4", "Fujifilm X-H1", "Fujifilm X-H2", "Fujifilm X-H2S", "Fujifilm X-M1", "Fujifilm X-Pro1", "Fujifilm X-Pro2", "Fujifilm X-Pro3", "Fujifilm X-S1", "Fujifilm X-S10", "Fujifilm X-T1", "Fujifilm X-T10", "Fujifilm X-T100", "Fujifilm X-T2", "Fujifilm X-T20", "Fujifilm X-T200", "Fujifilm X-T3", "Fujifilm X-T30", "Fujifilm X-T4", "Fujifilm X-T5", "Fujifilm X100S", "Fujifilm X100T", "Fujifilm X20", "Fujifilm X30", "Fujifilm X70", "Fujifilm XF1", "Fujifilm XF10", "Fujifilm XQ1", "Fujifilm XQ2", "Hasselblad CF-22", "Hasselblad CF-39", "Hasselblad CFV-16", "Hasselblad H3D-31", "Hasselblad H3D-31 II", "Hasselblad H3DII-50", "Hasselblad H4D-40", "Hasselblad H5D-50c", "Hasselblad H6D-100C", "Hasselblad X2D 100C", "Kodak DCS Pro SLR/n", "Konica Minolta ALPHA SWEET DIGITAL", "Konica Minolta ALPHA-5 DIGITAL", "Konica Minolta ALPHA-7 DIGITAL", "Konica Minolta DYNAX 5D", "Konica Minolta DYNAX 7D", "Konica Minolta DiMAGE A200", "Konica Minolta MAXXUM 5D", "Konica Minolta MAXXUM 7D", "LEICA M MONOCHROM (Typ 246)", "LEICA M11 MONOCHROM", "LEICA Q2 MONO", "Leaf AFi 5", "Leaf AFi 54S", "Leaf AFi 6", "Leaf AFi 7", "Leaf AFi 75S", "Leaf AFi-II 6", "Leaf AFi-II 7", "Leaf Aptus 17", "Leaf Aptus 22", "Leaf Aptus 54S", "Leaf Aptus 65", "Leaf Aptus 65S", "Leaf Aptus 75", "Leaf Aptus 75s", "Leaf Aptus-II 6", "Leaf Aptus-II 7", "Leaf Valeo 11", "Leaf Valeo 17", "Leaf Valeo 22", "Leica C (Typ 112)", "Leica C-Lux", "Leica CL", "Leica D-LUX (Typ 109)", "Leica D-Lux 2", "Leica D-Lux 3", "Leica D-Lux 4", "Leica D-Lux 5", "Leica D-Lux 6", "Leica D-Lux 7", "Leica DIGILUX 2", "Leica DIGILUX 3", "Leica M", "Leica M Monochrom", "Leica M10", "Leica M11", "Leica M8", "Leica M8.2", "Leica M9", "Leica Q (Typ 116)", "Leica Q2", "Leica Q3", "Leica S (Typ 007)", "Leica S2", "Leica SL (Typ 601)", "Leica SL2", "Leica T (Typ 701)", "Leica TL", "Leica TL2", "Leica V-LUX (Typ 114)", "Leica V-Lux 1", "Leica V-Lux 2", "Leica V-Lux 4", "Leica V-Lux 5", "Leica X (Typ 113)", "Leica X Vario (Typ 107)", "Leica X-U (Typ 113)", "Leica X1", "Leica X2", "Minolta DiMAGE A1", "Minolta DiMAGE A2", "Nikon 1 AW1", "Nikon 1 J1", "Nikon 1 J2", "Nikon 1 J3", "Nikon 1 J4", "Nikon 1 J5", "Nikon 1 S1", "Nikon 1 S2", "Nikon 1 V1", "Nikon 1 V2", "Nikon 1 V3", "Nikon B700", "Nikon COOLPIX A", "Nikon COOLPIX A1000", "Nikon COOLPIX P1000", "Nikon COOLPIX P330", "Nikon COOLPIX P340", "Nikon COOLPIX P6000", "Nikon COOLPIX P7000", "Nikon COOLPIX P7100", "Nikon COOLPIX P7700", "Nikon COOLPIX P7800", "Nikon COOLPIX P950", "Nikon D1", "Nikon D100", "Nikon D1H", "Nikon D1X", "Nikon D200", "Nikon D2H", "Nikon D2Hs", "Nikon D2X", "Nikon D2Xs", "Nikon D3", "Nikon D300", "Nikon D3000", "Nikon D300S", "Nikon D3100", "Nikon D3200", "Nikon D3300", "Nikon D3400", "Nikon D3500", "Nikon D3S", "Nikon D3X", "Nikon D4", "Nikon D40", "Nikon D40X", "Nikon D4S", "Nikon D5", "Nikon D50", "Nikon D500", "Nikon D5000", "Nikon D5100", "Nikon D5200", "Nikon D5300", "Nikon D5500", "Nikon D5600", "Nikon D6", "Nikon D60", "Nikon D600", "Nikon D610", "Nikon D70", "Nikon D700", "Nikon D7000", "Nikon D70s", "Nikon D7100", "Nikon D7200", "Nikon D750", "Nikon D7500", "Nikon D780", "Nikon D80", "Nikon D800", "Nikon D800E", "Nikon D810", "Nikon D810A", "Nikon D850", "Nikon D90", "Nikon Df", "Nikon E8400", "Nikon E8700", "Nikon E8800", "Nikon Z 6 2", "Nikon Z 7 2", "Nikon Z fc", "Nikon Z30", "Nikon Z5", "Nikon Z50", "Nikon Z6", "Nikon Z7", "Nikon Z9", "Nikon Zfc", "Olympus C7000Z", "Olympus C7070WZ", "Olympus C70Z", "Olympus C8080WZ", "Olympus E-1", "Olympus E-3", "Olympus E-30", "Olympus E-300", "Olympus E-330", "Olympus E-400", "Olympus E-410", "Olympus E-450", "Olympus E-5", "Olympus E-500", "Olympus E-510", "Olympus E-600", "Olympus E-620", "Olympus E-M10 Mark IV", "Olympus E-P7", "Olympus EVOLT E-420", "Olympus EVOLT E-520", "Olympus OM-1", "Olympus OM-D E-M1", "Olympus OM-D E-M1 Mark II", "Olympus OM-D E-M1 Mark III", "Olympus OM-D E-M10", "Olympus OM-D E-M10 Mark II", "Olympus OM-D E-M10 Mark IV", "Olympus OM-D E-M10 MarkIII", "Olympus OM-D E-M1X", "Olympus OM-D E-M5", "Olympus OM-D E-M5 Mark II", "Olympus OM-D E-M5 Mark III", "Olympus PEN E-P1", "Olympus PEN E-P2", "Olympus PEN E-P3", "Olympus PEN E-P5", "Olympus PEN E-PL1", "Olympus PEN E-PL1s", "Olympus PEN E-PL2", "Olympus PEN E-PL3", "Olympus PEN E-PL5", "Olympus PEN E-PL8", "Olympus PEN E-PM1", "Olympus PEN E-PM2", "Olympus PEN Lite E-PL10", "Olympus PEN Lite E-PL6", "Olympus PEN Lite E-PL7", "Olympus PEN Lite E-PL9", "Olympus PEN-F", "Olympus SP-570UZ", "Olympus STYLUS 1", "Olympus STYLUS SH-2", "Olympus STYLUS TG-4 Tough", "Olympus STYLUS XZ-2", "Olympus XZ-1", "PENTAX RICOH GR", "PENTAX RICOH GR II", "PENTAX RICOH GR III", "Panasonic LUMIX DC-FZ10002", "Panasonic LUMIX DC-FZ1000M2", "Panasonic LUMIX DC-FZ80", "Panasonic LUMIX DC-FZ81", "Panasonic LUMIX DC-FZ82", "Panasonic LUMIX DC-FZ83", "Panasonic LUMIX DC-FZ85", "Panasonic LUMIX DC-G100", "Panasonic LUMIX DC-G9", "Panasonic LUMIX DC-G90", "Panasonic LUMIX DC-G91", "Panasonic LUMIX DC-G95", "Panasonic LUMIX DC-G95D", "Panasonic LUMIX DC-G99", "Panasonic LUMIX DC-G99D", "Panasonic LUMIX DC-GF10", "Panasonic LUMIX DC-GF9", "Panasonic LUMIX DC-GF90", "Panasonic LUMIX DC-GH5", "Panasonic LUMIX DC-GH5M2", "Panasonic LUMIX DC-GH5S", "Panasonic LUMIX DC-GH6", "Panasonic LUMIX DC-GX7MK3", "Panasonic LUMIX DC-GX800", "Panasonic LUMIX DC-GX850", "Panasonic LUMIX DC-GX880", "Panasonic LUMIX DC-GX9", "Panasonic LUMIX DC-LX100M2", "Panasonic LUMIX DC-S1", "Panasonic LUMIX DC-S1H", "Panasonic LUMIX DC-S1R", "Panasonic LUMIX DC-S5", "Panasonic LUMIX DC-S5M2", "Panasonic LUMIX DC-TZ200", "Panasonic LUMIX DC-TZ202", "Panasonic LUMIX DC-TZ220", "Panasonic LUMIX DC-TZ90", "Panasonic LUMIX DC-TZ91", "Panasonic LUMIX DC-TZ92", "Panasonic LUMIX DC-TZ93", "Panasonic LUMIX DC-TZ95", "Panasonic LUMIX DC-TZ96", "Panasonic LUMIX DC-TZ97", "Panasonic LUMIX DC-ZS70", "Panasonic LUMIX DC-ZS80", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-CM1", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-FZ100", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-FZ1000", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-FZ150", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-FZ200", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-FZ2000", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-FZ2500", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-FZ300", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-FZ330", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-FZ35", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-FZ38", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-FZ50", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-FZ70", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-FZ72", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-FZH1", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-G1", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-G10", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-G2", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-G3", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-G5", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-G6", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-G7", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-G70", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-G8", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-G80", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-G81", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-G85", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-GF1", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-GF2", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-GF3", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-GF5", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-GF6", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-GF7", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-GF8", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-GH1", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-GH2", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-GH3", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-GH4", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-GM1", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-GM1S", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-GM5", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-GX1", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-GX7", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-GX7MK2", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-GX8", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-GX80", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-GX85", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-L1", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-LC1", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-LF1", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-LX1", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-LX10", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-LX100", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-LX15", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-LX2", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-LX3", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-LX5", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-LX7", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-LX9", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-TX1", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-TX2", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-TZ100", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-TZ101", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-TZ110", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-TZ60", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-TZ61", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-TZ70", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-TZ71", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-TZ80", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-TZ81", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-TZ82", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-TZ85", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-ZS100", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-ZS110", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-ZS200", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-ZS220", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-ZS40", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-ZS50", "Panasonic LUMIX DMC-ZS60", "Pentax *ist D", "Pentax *ist DL", "Pentax *ist DL2", "Pentax *ist DS", "Pentax *ist DS2", "Pentax 645D", "Pentax 645Z", "Pentax K-1", "Pentax K-3", "Pentax K-3 II", "Pentax K-30", "Pentax K-5", "Pentax K-5 II", "Pentax K-5 IIs", "Pentax K-7", "Pentax K-70", "Pentax K-S1", "Pentax K-S2", "Pentax K-m", "Pentax K-r", "Pentax K-x", "Pentax K100D", "Pentax K100D Super", "Pentax K10D", "Pentax K110D", "Pentax K2000", "Pentax K200D", "Pentax K20D", "Pentax MX-1", "Pentax Q", "Phase One IQ3 100", "Samsung GX-10", "Samsung GX-1L", "Samsung GX-1S", "Samsung GX-20", "Samsung NX10", "Samsung NX100", "Samsung NX11", "Samsung NX200", "Sony Alpha 7S II", "Sony Alpha 9", "Sony Alpha DSLR-A100", "Sony Alpha DSLR-A200", "Sony Alpha DSLR-A230", "Sony Alpha DSLR-A290", "Sony Alpha DSLR-A300", "Sony Alpha DSLR-A330", "Sony Alpha DSLR-A350", "Sony Alpha DSLR-A380", "Sony Alpha DSLR-A390", "Sony Alpha DSLR-A450", "Sony Alpha DSLR-A500", "Sony Alpha DSLR-A550", "Sony Alpha DSLR-A560", "Sony Alpha DSLR-A580", "Sony Alpha DSLR-A700", "Sony Alpha DSLR-A850", "Sony Alpha DSLR-A900", "Sony Alpha ILCE-3000", "Sony Alpha ILCE-5000", "Sony Alpha ILCE-5100", "Sony Alpha ILCE-6000", "Sony Alpha ILCE-6100", "Sony Alpha ILCE-6300", "Sony Alpha ILCE-6400", "Sony Alpha ILCE-6500", "Sony Alpha ILCE-6600", "Sony Alpha ILCE-7", "Sony Alpha ILCE-7 II", "Sony Alpha ILCE-7M3", "Sony Alpha ILCE-7M4", "Sony Alpha ILCE-7R", "Sony Alpha ILCE-7R II", "Sony Alpha ILCE-7R III", "Sony Alpha ILCE-7R III A", "Sony Alpha ILCE-7RM4", "Sony Alpha ILCE-7RM4A", "Sony Alpha ILCE-7RM5", "Sony Alpha ILCE-7S", "Sony Alpha ILCE-9M2", "Sony Alpha NEX-3", "Sony Alpha NEX-3N", "Sony Alpha NEX-5", "Sony Alpha NEX-5N", "Sony Alpha NEX-5R", "Sony Alpha NEX-5T", "Sony Alpha NEX-6", "Sony Alpha NEX-7", "Sony Alpha NEX-C3", "Sony Alpha NEX-F3", "Sony Alpha SLT-A33", "Sony Alpha SLT-A35", "Sony Alpha SLT-A37", "Sony Alpha SLT-A55", "Sony Alpha SLT-A57", "Sony Alpha SLT-A58", "Sony Alpha SLT-A65", "Sony Alpha SLT-A68", "Sony Alpha SLT-A77", "Sony Alpha SLT-A77 II", "Sony Alpha SLT-A99", "Sony Alpha SLT-A99 II", "Sony Cyber-shot DSC-RX1", "Sony Cyber-shot DSC-RX10", "Sony Cyber-shot DSC-RX10 II", "Sony Cyber-shot DSC-RX10 III", "Sony Cyber-shot DSC-RX100", "Sony Cyber-shot DSC-RX100 II", "Sony Cyber-shot DSC-RX100 III", "Sony Cyber-shot DSC-RX100 IV", "Sony Cyber-shot DSC-RX100 V", "Sony Cyber-shot DSC-RX100 VA", "Sony Cyber-shot DSC-RX100 VI", "Sony Cyber-shot DSC-RX100 VII", "Sony Cyber-shot DSC-RX1R", "Sony Cyber-shot DSC-RX1R II", "Sony DSC-HX95", "Sony DSC-HX99", "Sony DSC-R1", "Sony DSC-RX0", "Sony DSC-RX0M2", "Sony DSC-RX10M4", "Sony DSC-V3", "Sony ILCE-1", "Sony ILCE-7C", "Sony ILCE-7SM3", "Sony ILME-FX3", "Sony ILME-FX30", "Sony NEX-VG20", "Sony ZV-1", "iPad 7,1 backcamera", "iPad 7,3 backcamera", "iPad 8,1 backcamera", "iPad 8,2 backcamera", "iPad 8,3 backcamera", "iPad 8,4 backcamera", "iPad 8,6 backcamera", "iPad 8,7 backcamera", "iPad 8,8 backcamera", "iPad Pro (9.7-inch) backcamera", "iPad13,10 backwide", "iPad13,11 backwide", "iPad13,4 backwide", "iPad13,5 backwide", "iPad13,6 backwide", "iPad13,7 backwide", "iPad13,8 backwide", "iPad13,9 backwide", "iPad14,1 backwide", "iPad14,2 backwide", "iPad8,5 backwide", "iPhone 10,1 back camera", "iPhone 10,2 back camera", "iPhone 10,2 back telephoto camera", "iPhone 10,3 backcamera", "iPhone 10,3 backtelephotocamera", "iPhone 11,8 backcamera", "iPhone 6s Plus backcamera", "iPhone 6s backcamera", "iPhone 9,1 backcamera", "iPhone 9,3 backcamera", "iPhone 9,4 backcamera", "iPhone 9,4 backtelephotocamera", "iPhone SE backcamera", "iPhone10,4 wide", "iPhone10,5 telephoto", "iPhone10,5 wide", "iPhone10,6 back telephoto", "iPhone10,6 backwide", "iPhone11,2 back telephoto", "iPhone11,2 backwide", "iPhone11,4 back telephoto", "iPhone11,4 backwide", "iPhone11,6 back telephoto", "iPhone11,6 backwide", "iPhone12,1 backwide", "iPhone12,3 backtelephoto", "iPhone12,3 backwide", "iPhone12,5 backtelephoto", "iPhone12,5 backwide", "iPhone13,1 backwide", "iPhone13,2 backwide", "iPhone13,3 backtelephoto", "iPhone13,3 backwide", "iPhone13,4 backtelephoto", "iPhone13,4 backwide", "iPhone14,2 backtelephoto", "iPhone14,2 backultrawide", "iPhone14,2 backwide", "iPhone14,2 front", "iPhone14,3 backtelephoto", "iPhone14,3 backultrawide", "iPhone14,3 backwide", "iPhone14,3 front", "iPhone14,4 backultrawide", "iPhone14,4 backwide", "iPhone14,4 front", "iPhone14,5 backultrawide", "iPhone14,5 backwide", "iPhone14,5 front", "iPhone14,6 back camera", "iPhone14,6 front", "iPhone14,7 back", "iPhone14,7 back ultra-wide", "iPhone14,7 front", "iPhone14,8 back", "iPhone14,8 back ultra-wide", "iPhone14,8 front", "iPhone15,2 backtelephoto", "iPhone15,2 backultrawide", "iPhone15,2 backwide", "iPhone15,2 front", "iPhone15,3 backtelephoto", "iPhone15,3 backultrawide", "iPhone15,3 backwide", "iPhone15,3 front", "iPhone9,2 tele", "iPhone9,2 wide"]
```

I tried some filters provided by CIRAWFilter on CR2 photo. Nothing works.

Did I missed anything? I want to those filters provided by CIRAWFilter work on CR2 raw file badly. Is there any thing I can do?

New clues added:
[CIFilter and RAW image support on Yosemite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28257568/cifilter-and-raw-image-support-on-yosemite)

I tried to set decoderVersion to 5. Did not work.

```
rawFilter!.decoderVersion = CIRAWDecoderVersion(rawValue: "5")  
print(rawFilter!.decoderVersion)  
print(rawFilter!.supportedDecoderVersions)
```

> __C.CIRAWDecoderVersion(_rawValue: 6)
> [__C.CIRAWDecoderVersion(_rawValue: 6)]

Comment: You should use `URL(fileURLWithPath:)` for local files. Did you try to change something on the filter to see if it affects the image? I did a quick test and changed the exposure property and I got a changed image so it could be a quick test to see if the filter works.